# Does Go provide REPL?

Tags: go, read-eval-print-loop

The interactive environment is VERY helpful for a programmer. However, it seems Go does not provide it.  Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

No, Go does not provide a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)(read–eval–print loop).

However, as already mentioned, [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/) is very handy. The Go Authors are also thinking about adding a feature-rich editor to it.

If you want something local, consider installing [hsandbox](http://labix.org/hsandbox). Running it simply with `hsandbox go` will split your terminal screen (with `screen`) where you can write code at the top and see its execution output at the bottom on every save.

There was a `gotry` among standard Go commands, which used to evaluate expressions (with an optional package name), and could be run like `gotry 1+2` and `gotry fmt 'Println("hello")'` from shell. It is no longer available because not many people actually used it.

I have also seen third party projects for building a REPL for Go, but now I can only find links to two of them: [igo](https://github.com/sbinet/igo) and [go-repl](https://github.com/vito/go-repl). How well do they work I don't know.

My two cents: Speed of compilation makes writing a REPL possible for Go, as it has also helped building the tools mentioned here, but the same speed makes REPL less necessary. Every time I want to test something in Go that I can't run in Playground I open a simple `.go` file and start coding and simply run the code. This will be even easier when the `go` command in Go 1 makes one-command build process possible and way easier.

**UPDATE:** Latest weekly release of Go added `go` command which can be used to very easily build a file: write your `prog.go` file and run `go build prog.go && ./prog`

**UPDATE 2**: With Go 1 you can directly run go programs with `go run filename.go`

**UPDATE 3**: [`gore`](https://github.com/motemen/gore) is a new project which seems interesting.

Comment: TL;DR igo Others: Gore isn't very convenient as it requires pasting and Ctrl-D.  Something like Reinteract for Go would be awesomesauce.

Comment: There seem to be two REPL projects called "gore". This one is more actively maintained than the one in the answer: https://github.com/motemen/gore

Comment: Ha, I was just about to post the same thing. I've just been playing with `motemen/gore` there - it's pretty good.

Comment: https://github.com/motemen/gore  gore is pretty good and simple to use.

Answer (score 66):

### Try motemen/gore

> Yet another Go REPL that works nicely. Featured with line editing,
> code completion, and more.

[https://github.com/motemen/gore](https://github.com/motemen/gore#installation)

[image]

Comment: What is the program you are using to display your inputs? I love that

Comment: @jclasley it's in the repo's readme. https://github.com/cho45/KeyCast MacOS only

Answer (score 11):

You also have a recent (March 2013) project called **[gore](https://github.com/sriram-srinivasan/gore)** from [Sriram Srinivasan](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/), which can be useful:

> gore is a command-line evaluator for golang code -- a REPL without a loop, if you will.
>   It is a replacement for the go playground, while making it much easier to interactively try out bits of code: **gore automatically supplies boiler-plate code such as import and package declarations and a main function wrapper**.
>   Also, since it runs on your own computer, no code is rejected on security grounds (unlike go playground's safe sandbox mode).

Answer (score 8):

If you're a Vim user, the vim-go plugin (https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) provides a command (GoRun) to run and print the output of the current buffer. You still have to include all the boilerplate code of a main Go file, but it still provides a convenient way to quickly test code snippets in your local environment.

[image]

Comment: how can make the GoRun output in the current buffer。my vim, display that in the shell

Comment: vim-go all the way! However, to take this a step further I would remove the boiler plate code, put my 'package_test.go' in the split buffer & keep hammering :GoTest & :GoCoverage. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/)?

> About the Go Playground
>
> The Go Playground is a web service that runs on golang.org's servers.
> The service receives a Go program, compiles, links, and runs the
> program inside a sandbox, then returns the output.

Answer (score 5):

The [GoSpeccy](https://github.com/remogatto/gospeccy/tree/master/src/interpreter) project includes a builtin REPL of a restricted subset of the Go language. The implementation is using [goeval](https://github.com/sbinet/go-eval).

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can exploit the speed of compilation (as mentioned in other answers).

Have a look at [rango](http://godoc.org/github.com/emicklei/rango) that uses a generate-compile-run loop to mimic a REPL. You can also start it with imports and statements to begin an interactive session.

Answer (score 4):

**Gosh** is the interactive Golang shell. The goal is to provide an easy-to-use interactive execution environment.

https://github.com/mkouhei/gosh

Answer (score 3):

I've had some luck with the VSCode debugger, but it's fairly limited in so far as you cannot invoke function calls from the debug console [Debug: Function Calls not supported #2225](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2225).

Basically you set a breakpoint after properly configuring your `launch.json` file. Then you can drill down on the left in the variables side bar and enter variable expressions an the debug console.
[image: Debugging go file in VSCode to introspect through debugger]

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to try https://github.com/haya14busa/goplay
This enables you to run go code files from your terminal directly to the Go Playground

Answer (score 1):

Please also check [www.gorepl.com](http://www.gorepl.com) for go REPL and other REPLs

Comment: Dead link dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Go code can be run in a REPL-like way in Visual Studio Code with the Go extension and Code Runner extension. Click the Run triangle ▶ which is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to run the code and show the results in the Output pane at the bottom of Visual Studio Code.

When programming with Go Visual Studio Code will suggest additional Go extensions that can be installed to extend Visual Studio Code's functionality.

[image: Go running in Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 0):

**16-line Go Scriptable REPL written in Bash, for Linux:**

This will **NOT** open a REPL, but you can use it as a Scriptable REPL / Runtime, like you can with `python`, `python3`, `node`, `deno`, `bash`, etc.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $(cat $1 2> /dev/null) == "" ]]; then
  SCRIPT_P_FNAME=$2
  GORUN_ARGS=$1
  shift 2
else
  SCRIPT_P_FNAME=$1
  shift 
fi

cat ${SCRIPT_P_FNAME} | sed '/^#!/d' > wubbalubbadubdub.go

go run wubbalubbadubdub.go $@

rm wubbalubbadubdub.go
```

Save this as `/usr/bin/gorun` and give it executable permissions using:

```bash
sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/gorun
```

You can extend `gorun` to take arguments in the shebang-line with the above configuration. It's arguments will be in `$GORUN_ARGS` if you passed them.

If you use a shebang-line of `#! /usr/bin/env gorun` it will work, but any arugments passed in this shebag-line will go to `env` instead of `gorun`, which is probably not what you want, unless you don't care to pass arguments to `gorun` at all.

**Your Go Script, with a Shebang-line:**

```golang
#! /usr/bin/gorun

package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "strings"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`Hello World`)
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(os.Args[1:], ","))
}
```

Save this as `index.go`, for example. The content of this script is just demonstrative of being able to parse arguments passed to it via the CLI.

**Run your Go Script via the CLI (Option 1):**

```bash
./index.go arg1 arg2 arg3
```

**Run your Go Script via the CLI (Option 2):**

```bash
gorun index.go arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Before you build it, you'll have to remove the shebang-line. Maybe write another CLI like this called `gobuild` that does the same thing as `gorun`, except replacing `go run` with `go build`.

Honestly, I don't know why Go doesn't have a built-in REPL, or doesn't respect the shebang-line by default like all other runtimes.

I guess they really don't want you to write Go scripts, as it is intended to be a compiled language. Well, this changes that, lol.

Btw, you can do something similar for other compiled languges, it's just that Go is a good contender for this since `go run` is pretty quick by default due to the constraints placed on the language format.

If you didn't know, you can write scripts in the same manner as shown above with other runtimes such as `node`, `python` etc. and execute them in the same 2 ways as shown above as long as you change up the shebang-line accordingly. These runtimes respect the shebang-line by default. For example, you can use `#! /usr/bin/env node` in a NodeJS script and run it with either `./index.js` or `node index.js`. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/cosmos72/gomacro. Can be used as an alternative to bash scripts.

There's also https://github.com/d4l3k/go-pry, slightly different workflow.

I'll update this once I have a comparison with https://github.com/x-motemen/gore.