# How to run Go(lang) code directly from terminal/command line?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, command-line, go, terminal

I want to run simple go code directly from terminal/command line. For example:

```
go run "
package main
func main() {
println("hello")
}
"
hello
```

However golang allows code execution only from file. So maybe there are some ways how to emulate it? Like this:

```
go run file.go < echo "...."
```

But there should be no files after actions above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In command-line, only a project like [go-repl](https://github.com/vito/go-repl) would compile/run a multi-line go source code without leaving any `.go` file behind.
An alternative: [gore](https://github.com/sriram-srinivasan/gore):

```
$ gore
Enter one or more lines and hit ctrl-D
func test() string {return "hello"}
println(test())
^D
---------------------------------
hello
```

(Other repl-like solution are listed in "[Does Go provide REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513609/6309)")

Or you would need to develop a go wrapper which would internally create a source code and go run it, before deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a `gorun` tool which works well for small scripts. It compiles scripts on the fly, caching the binaries in /tmp.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/gorun

Although it's intended for scripting and not as a REPL, you could use it in various ways.

Although `gorun` has come from the Ubuntu community, it should work on any Linux distro because it uses vanilla Go source code via

```
$ go get launchpad.net/gorun
```

Comment: `go: missing Bazaar command` the above command throws me an error

Comment: @muthukumarhelius You need to install the Bazaar version tool as Ubuntu hosts their gorun-code in a bzr repo. See more here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoGetTools