# How to run Go language in windows?

Tags: go, ide

I have downloaded windows installer for GO language and installed it. But there seems to have no option to run it interactively like Python etc. How can I run Go interactively? Are there any IDE for the Go Language? Someone please explain me how can I do that.

Comment: use LiteIDE: https://github.com/visualfc/liteide                                                    Btw, not an interpreted language and has no interactive shell.

Comment: Intellij IDEA go plugin https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin is rather good!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28664334/6309

Comment: [IDEs and Plugins for Go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins)

Answer (score -1):

There are some Go REPL implementations out there. A quick google search returned:

https://github.com/motemen/gore

https://github.com/vito/go-repl

I haven't used them, but I assume they work similarly to Python's REPL.